# How to change node edge lines in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a bunch of nodes on each side of a central node. I am trying to find a way to position the node lines so that they go to the right or left side of the nodes.

So for this:
http://jsbin.com/ipuxub/4/edit?js,output

I want the lines for the Jerry node to go to right side of Elaine, George, Kramer, etc.

While I don't think this is possible now:

1. Is there a way to force it, trick it or make it look better?
2. If it is changing the Cytoscape JS code, any suggestions to where I begin or look at or what would need to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

Controlling edge control points more manually or adding support for node bend points are things we have planned to add in future, and I think either case would satisfy your use case.

However, we do not have the resources to do this in the short term:  Both cases require our side to plan how those features would fit in with the model and visual style system (cy.js css).

In the short term, if you want to control where edges are drawn, you have to adjust the positions of the connected nodes -- because the edge positions are inferred between them.  The first edge is straight between them, and for 2 or more beziers are used.

If moving node positions does not suffice for your usecase, the first steps would be for us to  discuss and plan how this feature would work and how it would fit into the system: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/359

Then if you're interested in implementing it, it would be a straightforward process.  We could direct you to the relevant parts of the code that would need to be changed etc over a Google+ call.

Thanks -M